# How to avoid specifying absolute file path while git-add

Tags: git, git-add

Using `git add` command becomes tedious once the file path becomes lengthy. For e.g.
`git add src_test/com/abc/product/server/datasource/manager/aats/DSManger.java`
Is it possible to bypass specifying absolute file path? May be using some kind of pattern or something?

I know that we can use `git gui`. But I want to do it using cmd line.

Thanks in advance for the inputs.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For unix-like systems you can always use the star to point to files, e.g.

```
 git add *DSManager.java
```

will include all DSManager.java files git can find within your source tree starting in your current working directory.

Comment: Apparently, this ONLY adds newly created files, but skipps modified files. Any reason for that?

Comment: For me this also works with modified files. Maybe this depends on the git version, bash version, operating system. I don't know. I'm on OSX 10.6 with git 1.7.5.4 and bash 4.2.10(2).

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't add modified files, only new files, on `Linux version 2.6.32 gcc version 4.4.7 Red Hat 4.4.7-17` (Godaddy Linux Hosting); git version 1.7.1

Comment: This works on Windows through git bash.

Comment: Works on Windows with powershell also.

Answer (score 58):

Here is another way to add files. Supported at the very least in git 1.7.1.

```
$ git add -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged      +61/-61 a/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 another/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> 2
```

Press `2` to select update, or type `u`.

```
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged      +61/-61 a/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 another/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
Update>> 2
```

Press the number corresponding to the file you want to stage. Separate multiple numbers with a comma, e.g. `1,2`.

```
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged      +61/-61 a/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
* 2:    unchanged        +1/-1 another/very/long/path/that/we/really/dont/want/to/type.txt
Update>>
```

Just press `[enter]` here.

```
updated one path

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> q
Bye.
```

Finally type `7` or `q` to quit.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is not shell dependent like globbing. Also, it can become difficult to write a good glob pattern to match only what you want to add when the file names can be very similar.

Comment: This has helped me a lot; my git version is 1.7.1 on a shared hosting account.

Comment: nice mention, this helps

Comment: Also think this should be the accepted answer, very useful to me.

Comment: this post just made my day :)

Comment: None of the options are for "restore", any reason why that is? I want to restore 3 files without having to /src/app/foo/bar/jemima/rhymer/filename.ts for each one. Even with tab-completion it's tedious.

Comment: This has been what I was looking for to add only certain files when there are long paths to each. Thank you!

Comment: this is by far the best answer and should definitely be the accepted one

Answer (score 36):

With bash, you can set "globstar" (`shopt -s globstar`) and then do:

```
git add **/DSManger.java
```

to add all files called DSManager.java present below the current directory.

(`**/` matches all directories and subdirectories.)

Comment: That's actually the nicer solution, since it only includes files called DSManager.java and omits files called OtherDSManager.java. However, your shell has to support the globstar option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.

To add all files (not yet added), use:

```
git add .
```

If you need to add all but one file, you cold add all, then remove the files using:

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

You can also add all files in a subdirectory with

```
git add subdir/
```

One thing that I know can be annoying is when you rename files, you need to add the new filename and git rm the old name. When renaming a directory this can be annoying. This (unix only) git alias solves this problem (put it in your ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[alias] ;add after this heading or create this heading if it does not exist
        addremove = !git add . && git ls-files --deleted | xargs --no-run-if-empty git rm
```

This adds all new files and removes all deleted files and stages it to the index.

Comment: wasn't hard. Rename dir then git add -A

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just say "git add DSManger.java" if your terminal window is currently cd into the proper folder (src_test/com/abc/product/server/datasource/manager/aats). So just do:

```
cd src_test/com/abc/product/server/datasource/manager/aats
git add DSManger.java
```

Otherwise, I can't think of any other way unless you make a separate repo.[image]

Comment: Right. That should work. But files to commit are from different packages hence it will be again tedious to everytime `cd`

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this sample bash script which I have created for this purpose. [Link to the Github Repo](https://github.com/pckrishnadas88/indexed-git)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script Name: git-bash.sh
#
# Author: Krishnadas P.C<pckrishnadas88@gmail.com>
# Date : 05-05-2018
#
# Description: A simple script to manipulate git files.
# TODO add more options and add Error Handlers. 

#declare color variables
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`

#print the current git branch
echo "On Branch - $(git branch)"
#Get only staged files
gitstaged=($(git diff --name-only --cached))

#Get changes not staged for commit
gitnotstaged=($(git diff --name-only))

#Get only untracked files
gituntracked=($(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard))

if [ $# -ge 3 ];
then
   if [ $2 == "st" ];
   then
       git $1 ${gitstaged[$3]}
   elif [ $2 == "nt" ]; 
   then  
    git $1 ${gitnotstaged[$3]}
   elif [ $2 == "ut" ]; 
   then  
    git $1 ${gituntracked[$3]}
   else
     echo "Invalid input provied."
   fi     
fi
#Get the new status after the command has been executed.
gitstaged=($(git diff --name-only --cached))

#Get changes not staged for commit
gitnotstaged=($(git diff --name-only))

#Get only untracked files
gituntracked=($(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard))
#print the staged files.
for i in ${!gitstaged[@]}; do
   if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "Changes to be committed:" 
   fi
   echo "${green}st$i - ${gitstaged[$i]}${reset}"
done
#print the changes not staged files.
for i in ${!gitnotstaged[@]}; do
   if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "Changes not staged for commit:" 
   fi
   echo "${red}nt$i - ${gitnotstaged[$i]}${reset}"
done
#print the untracked files.
for i in ${!gituntracked[@]}; do
   if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "Untracked files:" 
   fi
  echo "${red}ut$i - ${gituntracked[$i]}${reset}"
done

: 'Example how to:
#$ ./git-bash.sh 
Untracked files
ut0 - git-bash.sh
ut1 - git-status.txt
ut2 - test
$./git-bash.sh add ut 0
Staged files
st0 - git-bash.sh
st1 - git-status.txt
Untracked files
ut0 - test
ut stands for untracked files.
nt stands for notstaged tracked files.
st stands for staged files.
'
```

**Sample output**

```
$ ./git-bash.sh 
On Branch - * master
Untracked files:
ut0 - git-bash.sh
ut1 - git-status.txt
ut2 - test

$ ./git-bash.sh add ut 2
On Branch - * master
Changes to be committed:
st0 - test
Untracked files:
ut0 - git-bash.sh
ut1 - git-status.txt
```